# Xcode 11 (11A420a) not displaying "Embed in H/VStack" menu items when using Command-Click on declaration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I've been playing around with SwiftUI and I'm noticing all these tutorials mentioning to Command-Click `Text` for example and expecting the following menu items to appear in order to *Embed in HStack* for example:

[image]

The problem is I'm not seeing any of these "*Embed in H/VStack*" menu items appear. Even if I search for "Embed" it doesn't return anything.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

I'm on:

**Mojave 10.14.6** (18G95).

**Xcode Version 11.0** (11A420a).

Comment: You need Catalina for that

Comment: SwiftUI previews and inspectors are only available when running on macOS Catalina 10.15. [Xcode 11 Realse Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes?language=objc)

Comment: I am running Big Sur (11.5.1), still I can't see these options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SwiftUI previews and inspectors are only available when running on macOS Catalina 10.15.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes?language=objc

Answer (score 13):

You must have the canvas open for the "Embed in H/VStack" menu items to appear.

Press `Command + Option + Enter` to open the canvas and then select the code you want to embed and then `Hold Command + Left Click` to try again.

Confirmed on `Catalina (10.15.5)` and `Xcode (11.6)`

Answer (score 11):

Being on Catalina `(10.15.4 (19E287))` and Xcode `(11.4 (11E146))`, I've had the same problem.

I've noticed that the requested embed menu appears only when the Canvas is enabled (Editor > Canvas).

Answer (score 8):

I have discovered this happen because the Canva it is close, just return it by "Command + Option + Enter" and try again.

This works for me and I hope works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen them as shown but they do exist for me in `Xcode 11.4.1` under `Show Code Actions` rather than `Refactor`.

The shortcut to get there is `[Command][Shift][Left Click]` on a `SwiftUI` element.

[image: Right Click > Show Code Actions][image]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a defect in Xcode I believe. It happens in the 12 betas as well. For me it seems to come and go. The same project will work and then 5 minutes later refuse to shot it in the same project/file. I reported it to Apple but so far no response.

Comment: yea, none of the other answers are working for me.  SwiftUI rollout has potential but still kind of buggy.