# Automatic preview in Xcode 11 using macOS Catalina beta

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode11, macos-catalina

I've installed **macOS Catalina beta** last month and I used **Xcode beta 5**. Today I downloaded **Xcode 11** from developer.apple.com. After installing I started with new project with SwiftUI framework. Unfortunately I got a problem. When I clicked **resume** button from the canvas, the code is debugged but the canvas didn't show me **any simulator**. It only showed me **loading circle** and then **Xcode Application** automatically quit itself. I tried it several times. Does anyone know what is happening? 
Please help me!!!
Thanks for reading this.
[Mac OS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7p4Y.png)
[Xcode version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNtC1.png)

Comment: Their is dependency between OS version and xcode version. Please mention your OS version and xcode version.

Comment: My Mac's original version is Mojave 10.14.6. Bt I updated to Catalina beta. I downloaded Xcode 11 that released at 20th September. I don't know what's wrong. Before downloading Xcode 11, I used Xcode beta 5. The automatic preview perfectly worked. Thank for replying me. @PeterSmith

Comment: And what's your xcode version number ?

Comment: This is my version number. Version 11.0 (11A420a)

Comment: SwiftUI previews and inspectors are only available when running on macOS Catalina 10.15. - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055209/xcode-11-11a420a-not-displaying-embed-in-h-vstack-menu-items-when-using-comm/58055738#58055738)